# I would like to buy the Knock on Wood keychain patent

Tags: assignment, ca2505802a1

I am ready to buy this patent ([CA 2,505,802 A1](http://www.google.com/patents/CA2505802A1)), and am wondering how and who to contact about it.

Answer (score 1):

This application was filed only in Canada and never granted. It has been considered to be a dead application since April 29, 2009, due to CIPO being unable to deliver the Maintenance Fee Reminder (returned to sender, moved/address unknown). You can find all of this information in [CIPO](http://brevets-patents.ic.gc.ca/opic-cipo/cpd/eng/patent/2505802/summary.html).